# Unable to display Partial View as JQuery Mobile dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I put together a simple example:

I have a list of thumbnails and I want to display a bigger image when an image from the list is selected:

```
@if (Model.GalleryIcon.Any())
{
    foreach (var cell in Model.GalleryIcon)
    {  
        <a href="/Logo/MobileImage?url=@cell.TargetImagePath" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" ><img src="@cell.ThumbInvPath" /></a>        
    }    
}
```

`/Logo/MobileImage?url=@cell.TargetImagePath` returns a partial view where @Model is a imagePath string:

```
@model string

<div id="logo-image-wrap">
      <img src='@Model' id="logo-wrap-mobile-image"/>
      <br />
      <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
 </div>
```

This works is I set rel="external" on the  anchor and simply opens an image in new, separate page but it doesn't work as a Dialog box.
When an thumbnail image is selected from the list a blank dialog box comes up with "Undefined"

How can I mage my Partial view load with image details in a Dialog when a thumbnail is selected from the list?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detailed solution is posted here:

http://usnitch.blogspot.com/2012/08/jquery-mobile-how-to-dynamically-load.html

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT THREE:**

My apologies to anyone trying to make use of my answer. I somehow missed the whole "Mobile" part of the question, so the examples+explanation I had here were entirely irrelevant. If you want to see the code and whatnot from previous edits, click on the "edited" link below the answer.

After chatting on this problem with the OP, we think something like this may work (but needs to be tested before we know):

Modifying the generated anchors to add a hook for our jQuery bindings:

```
<ul>
...
    <li><a class="btn" href="someurl">Art</a></li>
...
</ul>
```

Then, we need to add a handler for the click event for these links:

```
$('a.btn').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.mobile.changePage( href, { role: 'dialog', transition: 'slide' } );
});
```

What this should do it make a request to the page we want to display, which is hijaxed by the jQuery Mobile framework. The second parameter tells the framework to display the page as a dialog rather than "navigating" to it.

Comment: Please. I don't have to load partial views for all items on the list , do I ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. It may be more obvious what I mean once I've posted the example.

Comment: Whenever. It's your question. Just remember to ask for explanation for anything that doesn't seem obvious.

Comment: Edited answer again. I think I over-thought the solution. See if the second example makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you Tieson. Like I said this was just a simple example. In case if I do have a more complicated model-bound Partial View that I need to display as a dialog, will I actually need to pre-load every instance that could potentially end up being a modal Dialog on the page ? If for example I have 100 thumbnail images on my list will I need to pre-load 100 placeholder partial views populated with model data into DIVs before I can properly open dialogs ? 
It doesn't make sense to me. Thanks agian

Comment: No, just one dialog target needs to be loaded somewhere on the page (or you could create an element in the DOM and target that). What the second example shows is that we take the `href` value from whatever link was clicked and inject that into the one placeholder before calling the `.dialog()` method. While the selector for the "on click" method selects many hyperlinks, it is triggered individually for each hyperlink, and so you reuse your "dialog" for each link.

Comment: Taking the second route - it doesn't work unfortunately. The image blinks as its being loaded in the DOM then an empty popup takes over the screen with "Undefined" in it.

Comment: Hmmm I actually KINDA got it to work by wrapping partial view in data-rel="page" and data-rel="content". One BIG problem though.. whenever dialog opens the site either refreshes ( and it triggers it go to to its homepage) or triggers the "Back" action while the dialog is already open. It completely skrews up JQuery rendering. Something's wrong...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15040/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-shenaniganz)

Comment: Tieson, as much as I appreciate spending so much time working on this this is not the correct solution. This is a JQueryUI-Mobile mix. After doing some reading I figured it out finally.

Comment: Awesome. You are allowed (encouraged, actually) to post and accept your own answer if you figure it out. Good job.

Comment: Two things: 

1) Partial view has two be wrapped in data-role="page" and data-role="content" as when loaded into DOM and displayed as a dialog JQuery will consider it as another page.
2) Javascript has to go into a header of the main, First index page. It cannot be  part of other views.
3) $( document ).delegate has to be used instead of Page load.

You're correct with the rest. I'll type out a blog entry and post a link in a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may try to call the dialog via an onclick event rather than inline statement on dynamic dom loading. By this way you may have a chance to load the created dom element rather than the one in process. On onclick Event you may also refresh the dom by .load before sending to the dialog.